# Сигнал  для редактирования БД, QTableView\QSqlRelationalTableModel

Tags: sqlite, qt, c++

Подскажите подходящий сигнал для редактирования БД. Необходимо сразу после редактирования пользователем ячейки таблицы послать запрос в БД об изменении данных. Стандартные `QSqlTableModel::OnFieldChange` и `QSqlTableModel::OnRowChange` метода setEditStrategy не подходят.

Кусок проблемного кода:

```
modelUserDatabase = new QSqlRelationalTableModel();
modelUserDatabase->setTable("cmp_words_translation");
modelUserDatabase->setRelation(1, QSqlRelation("en_words", "id", "en_word"));
modelUserDatabase->setRelation(2, QSqlRelation("ru_words", "id", "ru_word"));
modelUserDatabase->removeColumn(0);
modelUserDatabase->select();
modelUserDatabase->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);

viewUserDatabase = new QTableView();
viewUserDatabase->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
viewUserDatabase->setModel(modelUserDatabase);
viewUserDatabase->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
//Собственно проблема тут
QObject::connect(modelUserDatabase, SIGNAL(dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)), this, SLOT(changeWordInDictionary(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)));  
mainLayout->addWidget(viewUserDatabase);
```

P.S. Сигнал `dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)` посылается только при изменении первого столбца таблицы. Он бы подошел, если бы посылался и при изменении второго столбца.
О наследовании я также уже думал и не нашел подходящего метода\слота, из которого можно было бы эмитнуть свой сигнал. Нашел только в QTableWidget метод itemChanged, но виджет наследуется от QTableView и не подходит под задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте, унаследовав модель, переопределить метод `setData()`, в котором и вызывайте `submitAll()` модели после того, как успешно выполнится его базовый вариант. То есть:

```
bool MyModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role) {
   if(QSqlTableModel::setData(index, value, role)) submitAll();
}
```